# Questions about the treatment of anomalies

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, quantum-anomalies

I was reading Schwartz's QFT book, and in Chapter 30, he introduces the calculations of anomalies by evaluating objects like $\partial_\mu\langle J^{\mu 5}J^\nu J^\alpha\rangle$, where $J^5$ is understood to be the axial current, whereas $J$ is the usual vector current. It's clear to me that this correlation function will yield triangle diagrams with amputated external legs and it's also clear that, should the theory be anomaly free (in this particular case free of chiral anomalies), this object should vanish.

What is not clear to me is why are we looking at it in the first place. Why should we look at this and not directly at, for example, $\partial_\mu\langle J^{\mu 5} \rangle$, if the anomaly is in fact there, shouldn't this, at some loop order, yield a non-zero value and that's that? Isn't this precisely what is done when we calculate it via the Fujikawa method? Why is it different when we look diagrammatically?

Also as an aside, which is related, but not the same topic, the book states that seeing non-zero amplitude related to the $\pi^0\to\gamma\gamma$ decay is equivalent to stating that the composite operator coupled to the pion has a non-zero expectation value in the presence of a background EM field. The book says he'll derive it rigorously later on, but I don't even understand the intuition behind it, if someone could give me a brief holistic argument as to why this is the case I'd appreciate it as well.

Comment: Your aside could be it's own question, did you not skip ahead to see why it is that way first?

Comment: I agree, which is why I asked for a holistic argument just so I can get the intuition behind the idea, no need for a very complete answer. I did not skip ahead because, from the way Schwartz phrases it, there should be a way to see this intuitively without the toolset he'll introduce later on. So I thought I should attempt to understand the idea behind it first, that's all really.

Comment: My QFT is a bit too rusted to write it down completely, but I feel like the aside is answered by the LSZ reduction formula. It expresses the amplitude for the $\pi^0 \to \gamma\gamma$ in terms of the time-ordered correlation function of the composite operator coupled to the pion and two gauge fields. If the amplitude is non zero, this correlation function will be non-zero as well. In the presence of a background EM field, you can replace each gauge field insertion by their background values to get a contribution to the VEV of the composite operator.